# CherryPy JSON vs Form POST

Tags: python, json, forms, post, cherrypy

I have a web application developed in Python with the CherryPy framework. It uses many conventional HTML forms (with x-www-form-urlencoded data).

I'm developing an iOS application that I want to sync with the same database that the web application uses. To upload from iOS to the database I want to upload JSON in the HTTP request body with the HTTP POST method.

I tried writing a method in my web application to process the uploaded JSON data.

If my cherrypy.config looks like this

```
cherrypy.config.update({
    'environment': 'production',
    'log.screen': False,
    'log.access_file': '/home/adamek/webapps/cocoa_foody/logs/access.log',
    'log.error_file': '/home/adamek/webapps/cocoa_foody/logs/error.log',
    'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port': 15982,
    'tools.caching.on': False,
    'tools.encode.encoding': "utf-8",
    'tools.json_in.on': True,
})
```

my JSON pages work, but form submissions from the rest of my web application fail.

If I change the last line to `'tools.json_in.on': False,` My old form pages work again, but the JSON POST pages fail (cherrypy.request.json is None).

The requests to the JSON pages have `Content-Type: application/json` in the request headers.

The request to the other form pages have 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
'

Is there any way to have one CherryPy application handle both application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded, or do I need to have two separate CherryPy applications?

Comment: It should work with a single app, so you need to debug it. What do you mean by "form submissions fail"?

Comment: This is what I mean by form submissions fail    415 Unsupported Media Type

Expected an entity of content type application/json, text/javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! Just needed to add `'tools.json_in.force': False,` to the config.

```
cherrypy.config.update({
'environment': 'production',
'log.screen': False,
'log.access_file': '/home/adamek/webapps/cocoa_foody/logs/access.log',
'log.error_file': '/home/adamek/webapps/cocoa_foody/logs/error.log',
'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
'server.socket_port': 15982,
'tools.caching.on': False,
'tools.encode.encoding': "utf-8",
'tools.json_in.on': True,
'tools.json_in.force': False,
})
```

Comment: Good find, I didn't notice force is true by default