# cURL command returns HTTPError 415

Tags: batch-file, curl

I am trying to use the `curl` command from a batch script.

```
curl -k -o "C:\Temp\**8.txt" -X POST -H "auth-key: 1****G-*****" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data-binary @"***\test.txt" https://localhost:9443/security/backend-connectivity
```

I am seeing an error:

> ```
> HTTPError: (415, 'Expected an entity of content type application/json, text/javascript')
> ```

My JSON file is good.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope that's not a live auth-key that's intended to be kept secret. If it is, you should change it immediately.

Comment: Googling your error message in double quotes gives me overwhelming evidence that this is for a CherryPy setup. If this is the case, see if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022320/cherrypy-json-vs-form-post) helps. Otherwise, I have no idea and I'm not convinced you've given us enough information.

Comment: i am passing curl command 1 response : {a}

Response {a} to be passed in curl command 2 along with other parameters like provate key, pass phrase, connectivity 

Response of curl command 1 {a} is stored in a text file res.txt and I am adding parameters of curl command 2 ie private key to res.txt so that we could pass like 

Curl -k -o “outputofseccurl.txt” -X POST -H “auth key”: “****”, “Content-type”: “application/json” —data @“res.txt” https://local host:9443/

i ssee this error HTTPError: (415, 'Expected an entity of content type application/json, text/javascript')